# Right to Left support for bootstrap-sass

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left, bootstrap-sass

I've downloaded `bootstrap-rtl` from https://github.com/morteza/bootstrap-rtl in order to add Right to Left support for bootstrap. I put the `bootstrap-rtl.css` file in `app/assets/stylesheets` directory, but some of the styles are not applied. for example it doesn't affect navbar. Should I put that file in another location?

Comment: I guess you are importing bootstrap using `@import "bootstrap";`, try importing it before `bootstrap-rtl`. Rename `bootstrap-rtl.css` to `bootstrap-rtl.css.scss` and add `@import "bootstrap";` as first line (remove it from elsewhere) and see what happens

Comment: @Ruby Racer Why I need to import `bootstrap-rtl` in `custom.css.scss`? I simply put `bootstrap-rtl.css` in `app/assets/stylesheets` directory. Aren't all the css files in that directory applied automatically?

Comment: @Ruby Racer Yes I have imported `bootstrap-sprockets` and `bootstrap`.

Comment: Try defining the same thing twice and differently. The latter will override the former. That's why I'm telling you to force loading rtl AFTER standard bootstrap.

Comment: @RubyRacer Thanks, It works! Isn't this method inefficient? Isn't `bootstrap-rtl` applied twice this way?

Comment: For bootstrap, adding it to sprockets will import it to your library but it won't add it to the project. You need to also import it in a scss file. So, if you're not explicitly importing bootstrap-rtl and you add bootstrap-rtl.css, you're doing basically the same thing... once

Comment: I think using original bootstrap is better. After editing variables and compile process, use http://cssjanus.commoner.com to convert it.

Answer (score -1):

link it after **original** bootstrap.min.css